# wxString format Unicode character

Tags: c++, unicode, wxwidgets

```
for(int i='א'; i<='ת'; i++)
    incList.Add( wxString::Format("%c", wxT(i));
```

I'm trying to add Unicode character to the array using wxT. I'm getting this error

```
error: 'Li' was not declared in this scope
```

What is causing the error, and how can to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What's the line, in which you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxT()` is meant to operate on string literals, not variables.

You are probably wanting something along the lines of `wxString::FromUTF8(chars)` or `wxString mystring2(chars, wxConvUTF8)`. Simply passing a char array as parameter works as well, but is depending on the current locale.

Oh, and while we're at it...

```
for(int i='א'; i<='ת'; i++)
```

...note that using characters outside of the basic character set (basically, ASCII-7) in C++ source is *implementation-defined*. You should probably use escape sequences instead.

Answer (score 1):

wxT() is a macro defined thus:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#   define wxT(x)  L##x
#else // !Unicode
#   define wxT(x)  x
#endif
```

So of course `wxT(i)` becomes `Li`. It should be used only with string literals.

Besides, why would `wxT()` convert an int to a string? Use `itow` for that.